# Oxwall sidebar editing for ad rotator integration

Tags: php, css, ads, oxwall

I have to edit the right sidebar in oxwall website. There are two sections i.e my profile and add new section. I wan't to remove the add new section and put an ad rotator (The ad rotator will have 3 sections rotating ads at one time).

Please help me out that how can I do this. Which files must be edited?

Screenshot:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

click on option : customize this page [Which you will get in center-top of page] and then you can remove widgets from sidebar easily.